# Use BouncyCastle to generate Signed File

Tags: java, bouncycastle

I have a PDF file and I use this code to sign this file:

```
certificate = (X509Certificate) loadKeyStore(certificateFile, password).getCertificate(alias);
    privateKey = (PrivateKey) loadKeyStore(certificateFile, password).getKey(alias, alias.toCharArray());
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    BufferedInputStream inFile = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(origem));
    byte[] dates = new byte[inFile.available()];
    entrada.read(dates);
    entrada.close();
    CMSSignedDataGenerator genetateSign = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
    geradorAss.addSigner(privateKey, certificate, CMSSignedDataGenerator.DIGEST_SHA1);
    List certList = new ArrayList();
    certList.add(certificate);
    CertStore certs = CertStore.getInstance("Collection", new CollectionCertStoreParameters(certList));
    geradorAss.addCertificatesAndCRLs(certs);
    // Efetivamente assinar os dados de entrada  
    CMSProcessable content = new CMSProcessableByteArray(dates);
    String providerName;
    if (ks.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("JKS")) {
        providerName = BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME;
    } else {
        providerName = ks.getProvider().getName();
    }
    CMSSignedData signedDate = genetateSign.generate(content, providerName);
    signedDate = new CMSSignedData(content, signedDate.getEncoded());

    File f = Converter.converter("signedFile.pdf", signedDate.getEncoded());
```

But, the file f no open on reader. When I get the file f and run this code:

```
CMSSignedData data = new CMSSignedData(new FileInputStream(f));
```

Occur this error:

```
org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSException: Malformed content.
```

Someone can help me?

Summarizing:

I need to generate the final file after signing. For example, I have a test.pdf file, I want to sign and generate test_signed.pdf file. And this test_signed.pdf file must have the signature and should still be readable in your reader.

I'm waiting...

Answer (score 0):

PDF has an embedded signature inside the document, while CMS is signature itself. To extract and verify signature from PDF use iText library. Here is an [example](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=222).